# How to get element which you attached the handler to in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I am building a menu using unordered list in ReactJS. I am attaching the click event handler on the li, like this:

```
const menuItems = sidebarItems.mainItems.map((item) => {
    if (item.subitems.length > 0) {
        return (
            <li onClick={this.showSubmenu.bind(this)}>
                <span>{item.name}</span>
            </li>
        )
    }
});
```

But when my function showSubmenu(e) gets called, when I get e.target, the element I get is the span instead of the li. I thought I would be getting the li since I attached the event handler to the li.

How do I get the li via this method? I don't want to use jquery to attach event handlers to every li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `bind` from the event handler:

```js
class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    
    this.state = {
      items: [{ name: 'Item 1' }, { name: 'Item 2' }]
    }

    this.showSubmenu = this.showSubmenu.bind(this) 
  }
  
  showSubmenu(event) {
    alert(event.target.tagName)
  }
  
  render() {
    const { items } = this.state
    
    return (
      <ul>
        {items.map((item, index) =>
          <li
            key={index}
            onClick={this.showSubmenu}
          >
            {item.name}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Menu />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using your code, I am getting the actual item I am iterating upon, what I need is the li element to which I've attached the onClick handler. As in the li HTML element because I need to do some transitions for it upon click.

Comment: @g_b There you go. I've just updated my answer. Hope that helps :)